# Управление view у model в backbone.collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Как лучше и правильнее на ваш взгляд организовывать индвидуальные view у backbone.model, на уровне управления коллекцией? Сейчас я подписываюсь на события add у коллекции и добавляю новую вьюху для модели например так

```
addModel: function (model) {
 this.modelViews.push(new ModelView({model: model}));
}
```

И далее уже в рендере прохожусь с помощью `_.each()` по `modelViews()` и вызываю `render()` каждой `ModelView`
Знаю, что есть Marionnette где есть `CollectionView`, но возможно есть простые и удобные решения на самом Backbone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У себя я сделал класс на основе CollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({...})

Работает это так

```
var colViews = new CollectionView(collection);
```

Внутри класса тоже довольно просто. Получили коллекцию в конструктор и через listenTo подключились к ее событиям (add, remove, change, reset). При возникновении события метод получит на вход модель, которая изменилась/удалилась/добавилась. Тебе только остается перерендерить/создать один ItemView. Все остальное - это уже дополнительные плюшки, такие как к примеру сортировка.

В самом бекбоне нет средств для CollectionView. Но добавить такой функционал проще простого.

Если хочешь, могу сюда выложить мой класс. Кстати, он во многом похож на марионетовский.

Comment: Спасибо, мысль ясна, хорошая идея, думаю, так и сделаю.